# Call a javascrip function in a button's link option from Divi (wordpress theme)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, popup, divi

First of all, thank you in advance for any help you can give me.
I'm not a coder, at all.
I'm a photographer (https://lucky4shop.pt/portfolio/) that just happens to know a bit about Wordpress websites and can read css/html but I don't know how to code in any language.

That said, here's my problem...
I'm creating a Wordpress website with the Divi theme/builder for a restaurant that has 2 locations.
On the homepage, I created a button that activates a popup using a plugin called "Popups for Divi" that basically takes a section created by Divi Builder and makes it a popup.
The popup shows 2 buttons that come from an online ordering system called GloriaFood, each button for each restaurant.
The buttons are implemented through a shortcode.
When the user clicks one of the buttons, it shows the Menu that is created in GloriaFood but the popup doesn't go away unless the user clicks on the "X" to close it.
I'm trying to find a way for it to close automatically when the user selects one of the restaurants.
Divi Builder has an option to add a link to the code area that is created through the shortcode and I know that the popups plugin has a "hide function but I don't know how to implement that upon the action of a button click.

I'll leave some links here to relevant information:

- How the button is added: https://www.gloriafood.com/restaurant-ideas/add-online-ordering-button-wordpress
- Functions of the popup plugin: https://divimode.com/divi-popup/ (you have to scroll down to find them)
- [Screenshot for the shortcodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOc5E.jpg)
- [Link option on the builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdaKd.png)
- [Advanced options of the "Code" Module, in case this helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmGPY.png)